# Routing with either or proposition in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'd like to have a route setup like the following

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Static content handler",
    "content/{name}.{type}",
    new { controller = "StaticHandler", action = "StaticContent" });
```

But I'd like to also route `scripts/{name}.{type}` to the same controller and action and I'd rather not add another routing method if I can get away with it.

Can I set it up with something like `(content|scripts)/{name}.{type}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use a **RoutingConstraint**

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Static content Handler2",
    "{folder}/{area}.{type}",
    new { controller = "StaticHandler", action = "StaticContent" },
    new { folder = "scripts|content" } );
```

That last `new {}` will use the regex to tell the router that only use this route if folder is "scripts" or "content"